# Angular Multiple Entry Points with AOT

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an angular app that is compiled with webpack and uses multiple entry points:

```
    entry: {
        'app1': helpers.root('src', 'app1', 'main.ts'),
        'app2': helpers.root('src', 'app2', 'main.ts')
    }
```

I use the `CommonsChunkPlugin` to merge vendor files between these apps, which works great. However, I would now also like to use AOT compilation.

Using `@ngtools/webpack` I can only aotify one app. Is there a way to do this for both apps?

```
    new ngToolsWebpack.AngularCompilerPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: helpers.root('tsconfig.json'),
        entryModule: helpers.root('src', '[name]', 'app', 'app.module#AppModule'),
    }),
```

Using `[name]` (similar to webpack's `output`) does not work (see above). Is there a way to achieve the same thing another way?

Comment: I have now chosen to ignore the CommonsChunksPlugin in favour of the AOT performance gains and file size reductions. Not sure if there is a way to use both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Do not specify `entryModule`.

```
...
            plugins: [
            new AngularCompilerPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: ./tsconfig-aot.json,
            }),
    ]

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with Aot compilation, it does not allow you to build multiple apps by using multiple **entryModule**. If you want to perform AoT compilation then you will need to split the app1, app2 over to two webpack configurations. Each config will have the following:

```
app1.config.js:
     new ngToolsWebpack.AngularCompilerPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: helpers.root('tsconfig.json'),
        entryModule: helpers.root('src', '[name]', 'app', 'app1.module#AppModule'),
    }),

app2.config.js:
    new ngToolsWebpack.AngularCompilerPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: helpers.root('tsconfig.json'),
        entryModule: helpers.root('src', '[name]', 'app', 'app2.module#AppModule'),
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're using webpack 4, you shouldn't be using the commonsChunk plugin, you should use Optimize.splitChunks. It works fine with AOT.